# why is my google analytics not working after deployment on nextjs?

Tags: google-analytics, next.js, environment-variables

just set up google analytics to my site. It was working locally until I converted the api key to an .env.local file. I then added the environment variable on vercel and deployed it and now it just says no data available. Not sure, what happened. Can somebody take a look at my code?

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Script from 'next/script'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  import('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
  
  return (
    <>
  
  <Script 
   
   strategy="lazyOnload"
   src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_GOOGLE}`}/>

<Script strategy="lazyOnload">
        {`
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_GOOGLE}');
                `}
   </Script>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed this.

was missing the `PUBLIC` prefix.

should have been `NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).